# Simple form text input fields as part of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, simple-form

So I have 3 text input fields and each one represents a co-ordinate and they are stored in the array format `[x, y, z]` in my model.

I am trying to use the input fields to work together to produce an array submitted with the form. My code currently:

```
=f.input_field :coordinates[0], value: "1"
=f.input_field :coordinates[1], value: "2"
=f.input_field :coordinates[2], value: "3"
```

So my hoping is that I can use the `coordinates` param in the controller to save it to the database.
The issue is that with this setup the html produced is `<input value="1" name="shape[o]" id="shape_o">` when it should be `<input value="1" name="shape[coordinates][]" id="shape_coordinates_0">`

N.B. I already have `serialize :coordinates` in the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your custom attributes directly like this:

```
= f.input_field :coordinates, input_html: { value: 1,
                                            id: "shape_coordinates_0", 
                                            name: "shape[coordinates][]" }
```

But I suggest to create `attr_readers` in your model for each coordinate and then unite it in array:

```
# model:
class Shape < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :x, :y, :z #since you want to serialize it

  before_create :build_coordinates

  private

  def build_coordinates
    self.coordinates = [x, y, z]
  end
end
```

In this case your view will look much easy like:

```
=f.input_field :x, value: "1"
=f.input_field :y, value: "2"
=f.input_field :z, value: "3"
```